# Set Width and Height from Bitmap or ImageView to CustomView

Tags: java, android, view, android-custom-view

I'm trying to get *Width* and *Height* of `Bitmap` and set them as Layout Parameter of `CustomView`

**JAVA :**

```
 private void setBg() {
        drawView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        drawView.getLayoutParams().height = orginalBitmap.getHeight();
        drawView.getLayoutParams().width = orginalBitmap.getWidth();
        relativeLayout.addView(drawView);
    }
```

**XML :**

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_below="@+id/clear">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fullimg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

But the code above doesn't work, when I run the app I get this

[image]

the emojis, for example, should stop right in the corner of image view but instead of that it still appears in the two empty spaces.

Comment: can you please provide more explanation of what you want to achieve and what is your problem ?

Comment: @ismailalaoui thank you for your comment what I want is to make the `drawView` take the same width and height of `ImageView`

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use this method instead , you have to set the layout params this way and then add them to your drawView

```
 private void setBg(){

    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = drawView.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = orginalBitmap.getWidth();
    params.height = orginalBitmap.getHeight();
    drawView.setLayoutParams(params);
    relativeLayout.addView(drawView);

   }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but unfortunately, it's giving me `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.width' on a null object reference`

Comment: I have initialized it before, and I get the same error

Comment: what about your originalbitmap ? it cause the nullpointer issue

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've done, and it works well

```
  mDensity = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    actionBarHeight = (int) (110 * mDensity);
    bottombarHeight = (int) (60 * mDensity);
    viewWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    viewHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels - actionBarHeight - bottombarHeight;
    viewRatio = (double) viewHeight / (double) viewWidth;
    bmRatio = (double) orginalBitmap.getHeight() / (double) orginalBitmap.getWidth();
    if (bmRatio < viewRatio) {
        bmWidth = viewWidth;
        bmHeight = (int) (((double) viewWidth) * ((double) (orginalBitmap.getHeight()) / (double) (orginalBitmap.getWidth())));
    } else {
        bmHeight = viewHeight;
        bmWidth = (int) (((double) viewHeight) * ((double) (orginalBitmap.getWidth()) / (double) (orginalBitmap.getHeight())));
    }
    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    lparams.height = bmHeight;
    lparams.width = bmWidth;
    drawView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
```

Comment: @ismailalaoui, of course, thank you and Eid Mubarak ^^

Comment: thanks my friend and eid mubarek for you as well ^^